# Visualizing the training progress in Keras with Hualos

Tags: python, keras, visualization, diagnostics

I am trying to follow the instructions here https://github.com/fchollet/hualos
to visualize the training progress in Keras.  In the aforementioned page I read:

> Hualos - Keras Total Visualization project
>
> For now, this is a simple demo where a Flask server exposes an API to
>   publish and consume events in the form of JSON objects. The Keras
>   callback RemoteMonitor can publish events to the server, and the
>   Hualos landing page listens to the server and displays incoming data
>   on a c3.js graph.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> start the server: python api.py
> load the landing page: http://localhost:9000/
> launch a Keras experiment with the RemoteMonitor callback:
> ```

```
> from keras import callbacks
> remote = callbacks.RemoteMonitor(root='http://localhost:9000')
> 
> model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
> validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), callbacks=[remote])
```

Moreover:

> Dependencies:
>
> ```
> Python:
>     Flask
>     gevent
>
> JS (included in the repo):
>     d3.js
>     c3.js
> ```

I have installed both Flask and gevent successfully.

My code is the following using the mnist test data for brevity which I downloaded as a csv file from here: https://pjreddie.com/projects/mnist-in-csv/

```
from keras import callbacks
remote = callbacks.RemoteMonitor(root='http://localhost:9000')

X = mnist.iloc[:, 1:].values
y = to_categorical(mnist.iloc[:, 0])

X =  X.astype('float32')
y =  y.astype('float32')

X /= 255  # ATTENTION!  Normalization is critical!!!

n_cols = X.shape[1]

# Create the model: model
model = Sequential()

# Add the first hidden layer
model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (784,)))

# Add the second hidden layer
model.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu'))

# Add the output layer
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Fit the model
model.fit(X, y, validation_split = 0.3, epochs=3, callbacks = [remote])
```

Which results in the following output:

```
Train on 7000 samples, validate on 3000 samples
Epoch 1/3
7000/7000 [==============================] - 1s 100us/step - loss: 0.7812 - acc: 0.7717 - val_loss: 0.3036 - val_acc: 0.9153
Epoch 2/3
3296/7000 [=============>................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3139 - acc: 0.9072

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.py:606: UserWarning: Warning: could not reach RemoteMonitor root server at http://localhost:9000
  'root server at ' + str(self.root))

7000/7000 [==============================] - 0s 55us/step - loss: 0.3051 - acc: 0.9111 - val_loss: 0.2616 - val_acc: 0.9213
Epoch 3/3
2400/7000 [=========>....................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2613 - acc: 0.9237

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.py:606: UserWarning: Warning: could not reach RemoteMonitor root server at http://localhost:9000
  'root server at ' + str(self.root))

7000/7000 [==============================] - 0s 63us/step - loss: 0.2397 - acc: 0.9284 - val_loss: 0.2350 - val_acc: 0.9320

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.py:606: UserWarning: Warning: could not reach RemoteMonitor root server at http://localhost:9000
  'root server at ' + str(self.root))
```

In fact when I try to run the command :

```
python api.py
```

I am getting an exception:

```
 (base) D:\Mint_ns>python api.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pattern.server import App
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pattern'

(base) D:\Mint_ns>conda install -c asmeurer pattern
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pattern
  - tensorflow
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

This is kind of bizarre because the whole point is to use Hualos to work with Keras which runs with TensorFlow as its backend.

How can I  make this work?

Comment: Have you started running the server as the read me suggests? It sounds like your Hualos server is not running.

Comment: @nuric: Thanks for the suggestion.  When I try to run the command I get an exception.  See my updated question.